# Parsing USvideos.csv file using java

Tags: java, regex, csv, regex-group

I've been using `,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")+$)` regex for parsing csv file but it's not parsing out properly. Because some of descriptions have spaces, newlines and \n literal.
Help to parse it out properly.

```
UKserM-i0_A
vRf3azp1pak
PV_GHHXy7Po
JNyZ49q4vrU
99t4EBwIAt8,18.14.06,"Shawn Mendes Answers the Web's Most Searched Questions | WIRED","WIRED",24,2018-05-24T16:00:23.000Z,"ott autocomplete"|"shawn mendes"|"mendes"|"shawn mendes interview"|"shawn mendes autocomplete"|"shawn mendes wired autocomplete"|"shawn mendes music"|"shawn mendes tattoos"|"shawn mendes funny"|"shawn mendes funny moments"|"shawn mendes musician"|"shawn mendes songs"|"shawn mendes wired"|"shawn"|"shawn mendes wired autocomplete interview"|"shawn mendes tats"|"shawn mendes interview 2018"|"wired"|"wired.com",2310794,105783,558,2718,https://i.ytimg.com/vi/99t4EBwIAt8/default.jpg,False,False,False,"Shawn Mendes takes the WIRED Autocomplete Interview and answers the internet's most searched questions about himself. 

Shawn Mendes' self titled album is out Friday May 25th.Still haven’t subscribed to WIRED on YouTube? ►► http://wrd.cm/15fP7B7 


ABOUT WIRED
WIRED is where tomorrow is realized. Through thought-provoking stories and videos, WIRED explores the future of business, innovation, and culture.Shawn Mendes Answers the Web's Most Searched Questions | WIRED"
UhiXEgqhBWs
voG07pt-KYI
```

Csv file --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/19sKLeL_a48pMEj_G0ii-yjnkXcaDnamh/view?usp=sharing